# Ajax requests not open to everyone

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-2

I've created a webapp using CodeIgniter. There are several places where I use ajax in the application.

I want to know if there is a way where I can stop direct access and query to the ajax controller and only allow legitimate ajax requests originating from the page to be processed.

Thanks.

Comment: An AJAX request is just a simple HTTP request. Why do you want to stop direct access?

Comment: I know it may be hard to stop a determined person, but, I want to know if there is a way to stop people from accessing the ajax result page directly. It shows results from a database(nothing that needs to be protected) but I would want only the intended use for it rather than have someone come and scrape my database from it.

Comment: But you display the database results on the page anyways, right?

Comment: The short answer is it's not possible to do what you want. However You can define some IP based limitation rules to prevent users from scrapping the database (limit the amount of queries in a specific amount of time) or use a captcha in your `Ajax` form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this without a problem. The CodeIgniter input class has a method called is_ajax_request(). Simply check for this at the start of your controller action. For example:

```
function ajax_save() {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        //continue on as per usual
    } else {
        show_error("No direct access allowed");
        //or redirect to wherever you would like
    }
}
```

If you have controllers that are designated completely for ajax calls, you can put that if statement into the constructor `function __construct()` for the controller. Remember to call parent::__constructor() first though!

Edit: As for "originating from the page", you should probably be doing authentication + security checks (likely via session so that you don't hit the database) on your ajax request. So a rogue user not affiliated with your webapp shouldn't be able to send an ajax request manually anyways. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That just checks to see if an "is ajax" flag is set in the HTTP headers. Anyone can set that flag for any request. It is useful only for deciding what the best format of data to return is. It won't provide any security.

Comment: Agreed. Not hacker proof, but stops random requests in the application (i.e. from hrefs) from unwittingly accessing AJAX controller actions.