# Issues with my site's security built with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, url, controllers

I'm having issues when it comes to make my site secure from attacks.

First of all, my site is ordered in a test server with this structure below 
[image]

The issue comes when I have to define the security for the admin panel.

What I want:

1. To avoid direct access to controllers without being logged to the site
2. To prevent my site from being attacked by hackers
3. To keep safe my database from hackers

How do I do that? So far what I have done is this:

placed in every controller this code:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

which I understand it is supposed to prevent from direct access to controllers, but it is not working...I can access without being logged to every function in every controller..

I have also coded this function for storing user's data in session:

```
public function receiveLogin(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->data['error_message'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();   
    }else{
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $user = $this->user_model->checkUserLogin($username,$password);

        if (!empty($user)){
            $admin_data = array(
                'admin_id' => $user->u_id,
                'admin_name' => $user->u_name,
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($admin_data);
            redirect('admin/showDashboard');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', 0);
            $this->data['error_message'] = 'Los datos de ingreso son incorrectos';
            redirect('login');
        }               
    }
}
```

I have also configured my routes for shorten url, and that is functioning well.

Can somebody please explain me how to accomplish what I need? the posts I have found about this does not talk about this 3 security issues I have asked..

**which are the best practices for this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect controller against direct access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888572/how-to-protect-controller-against-direct-access)

Comment: @Mhakvoort I'm sorry but what I can see is that your answer is a duplicate from user coderabbi in the post you mentioned, not my question

Comment: First, ```defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');``` prevents DIRECT access to the controller files- this means that the user can't open up the controller's php file directly. This does NOT protect the ROUTE from direct access- the user can still access the route which accesses this controller file. This if only checks to see if the file is loaded through the codeigniter system. What you need to do is check to see if the user is logged in successfully and has an active session for each controller method you want to protect.

Comment: @MikelBitson no I get that part...I'm still researching on how to prevent direct access without being logged

Comment: Limon, I'm confused here- wouldn't you just write a check at the very top of whatever method you want to protect that checks to see if the user is logged in, if they're logged in you do your method logic, if the session isn't set and they're not logged in it just returns an error about being logged in or redirects the user to the login page?

Comment: @MikelBitson I know I cant put an if in every controller and check manually if it's logged or not, but it seems a solution that lacks automatization (maybe I´m wrong..this is why I ask for expert opinions here in stckvflw)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, CodeIgniter does not have a standardized process for this. Laravel would use middleware, but in codeigniter you have to make your own base class that would somehow contain this logic, like this chap does here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796663/codeigniter-login-check-for-all-functionstabs

Comment: I'm only talking about blocking controller methods from authorized users- keeping your database secure is something you must do with every query. Always use prepared statements and consider all user input malicious. There is no golden arrow for security, all of the code you add to codeigniter must check on it's own that the user's input is valid and can be saved to the database. CodeIgniter will not keep your site secure, only you can.

Comment: @MikelBitson thanks Mikel, if you like you can write an answer with all this and I would be happy to mark it as accepted (and also to put some tips for the database ;) )

Comment: You have to put this code even in views and models. Not in controllers only.

Answer (score 2):

I notice from your comment you don't want to include a login check in every function, that's understandable but not necessary.

Remember that the controller is just a class, so you can do the login check in the contructor:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent:__construct();
    $this->loggedIn();
}
```

Just remember to override the parent constructor, otherwise your controller will probably not function correctly.

Also note that this will do the logged in check for all functions in the controller, so you would need to have a separate controller for non-logged-in pages.

Another neat way is to use [traits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), you will need at least php version 5.4, but it's very useful for abstracting logic like this. You can create a trait which does the login check, include it in the controller where authentication is required, and just call a `$this->loggedIn()` or whatever you called the function at the top of the controller function which requires the user to be logged in, and let the trait redirect the user if they're not logged in

Comment: Might recommend doing stuff like this in a core controller aswell.

Comment: @killstreet why is it better to place this function in a core controller? so it can be called from every other controller?

Comment: Depends, in case of an admin panel you use the constructor to execute it every time you load a page that's inside the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

simplest thing is to put your application and system folder one level above the public html folder, then nothing is accessible!

```
application/public_html/
system302/public_html/
         /public_html/index.php
```

in your index.php file

```
$application_folder = '../application';
$system_path = '../system302';
```

for logging in -- put your login check code somewhere like a model, autoload the model so its always available, then call the login in the class constructor. Then all  the methods in the class are protected and you are not repeating a bunch of session checking code in your controllers.

Comment: how do I configure routes if I do this?

Comment: and how it is supposed to find my main controller with the first page of the site?

Comment: so in the index.php file, you set where your application and system folders are. the 'route' starts at the index.php file. Codeigniter does not need your controller structure to be the same as the server to create a route. but probably easiest just try it and you will see how it works!

Comment: I don't have an index.php file, my index would be a function inside admin controller (for the control panel), for the frontend its a main class controller

Comment: no not a controller file. its the main index.php for codeigniter. take a look at that file and you will see that it loads your system and application.

Answer (score 0):

The best security you could get would be using htaccess, as I also see that you are trying to create security for the admin panel, and depending on how you use the controllers (Some people use the admin controller for everything on their admin panel) I would recommend using a core controller.
Inside the core controller you use the following code:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->uri->segment(1) == "admin"){
            $this->checkLoginAdmin();
        }
    }

    function checkLoginAdmin(){
        if(isset(!$this->session->userdata('admin_id'))){
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "You must login first.");
            redirect("admin/login");
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you need to load the uri helper for this, depending on which version of codeigniter you use I would recommend putting that inside the autoloader of CodeIgniter. Also depending on the URL for the admin panel, this code will do it's work once your url looks like : www.example.com/admin

Even going to www.example.com/admin/test will not be allowed if you haven't loggedin.

Answer (score -3):

The CodeIgniter Input Class has a method called `is_ajax_request()` for this purpose.

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    //do something
} 
else {
    show_error("No direct access allowed");
    //or redirect
}
```

Comment: I don't see him asking for only accepting Ajax requests? And even if he did, faking an ajax request is as simple as adding a header.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but this is the canonical CodeIgniter solution to that question

Comment: But if he's not using Ajax, this will make his script fail?

Comment: Not at all related to the question. Certainly not a 'canonical CodeIgniter solution to that question' as it isn't even related to the question...