# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ssl

I have a WordPress site and I am getting an error from my godaddy seal.  I have the html for the verify image in a widget section of the footer of my site.

When I reload the page and check firebug I am getting this error in the console.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://seal.godaddy.com/setSealAttr?sealID=ID#. This can be fixed
>   by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

I have tried to look up information on this issue and it's a bit over my head.  Can anyone fill me in on what is throwing this error and how I might go about fixing the issue?  I am just trying to understand how this error happens. Is it a conflict issue with jquery somewhere, or is it the way the seal is being loaded or perhaps the time it is being loaded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may enable cross domain requests on your server http://stackoverflow.com/a/5009126/2375207 ... Or host your wordpress on seal.godaddy.com ... or cheat by implementing a proxy on your server, which answer is then sent to your wordpress

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Regarding

> This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS

and the fact you are using WordPress, you can create a proxy very easy like this :

proxy.php :

```php
<?
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
?>
```

Then you want to call a resource outside the domain, as with AJAX, use proxy.php to fake that you are trying access the resource from the same domain. Like :

```js
var url= "my-external-resource.com?param=value";
url = 'proxy.php?url='+url:
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Here the result is expected to be JSON, but just change header / datatype to HTML, XML or whatever if needed.

---

**Update** : @Jason raises an interesting point about security. I totally agree. Under normal circumstances one could prevent remote access to files by `.htaccess` and a `<Files>` directive :

```xml
<Files proxy.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

...but this is not satisfactory, since it will prevent using `proxy.php` in AJAX calls as well. A solution is to check if `proxy.php` is called by another script :

```php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('You are not allowed to access this file.');     
}
```

This will allow using proxy.php in javascript AJAX calls, but prevent direct access from remote (or locally). See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756970/1407478)** for more about `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Musik8101 Create a proxy.php as above, and place it in the root. Then change your ajax call to `proxy.php?url=<your original url>` (without < > characters off course)

Comment: @davidkonrad Bro I am also getting similar error . But My website is not wordpress although it works like one here is the url inmotico.com. Can you tell me how to make proxy server for that ?

Comment: Here is the query which I raised [Link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883261/making-ajax-call-result-into-cross-origin-request-blocked-error)

Comment: @Vikram Anand Bhushan, exactly the same way as above. It is simply just a small bridge, or proxy, to overcome the same origin policy.

Comment: I tried it bro but nothing happens I tried it same like above  Can I make the proxy on the same php page from where I am doing the AJAX() call

Comment: That solution looks pretty dangerous. Is it not an open proxy?

Comment: when I do this it is returning the information and ip addres for my server not my machine?

Comment: I created `proxy.php` in my theme's root directory. And edited my getJSON's `url` according your code. But I got 404 error in my browser's console. 

This is the URL in my browser's console: `https://origin-site-address.com/checkout/proxy.php?url=https://inquery.ir/:80?...`

Did I do anything wrong? Maybe placed `proxy.php` in a wrong directory?

I've tried many ways to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, including adding code or trying several plugins. Still getting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Answer (score 6):

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://fscebook.comxa.com/index.php',
      crossDomain: true,
      data: {user:user, pass:pass},
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {

        if($.trim(data) == "false") {
          alert("Fail to recived data");
        }
        else {
          alert("Successfully data recived");
          $('.results').html(data);
        }

      }
    });
```

Comment: In to .htaccess RewriteBase /
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" file put and in your serverfile write in index.php 
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo "true";
?>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the glyphicons-haflings-regular.woff fonts that came with bootstrap ver3. After adjusting the css to place the font-family declaration before any and all tag declarations my problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Use headers for solve cross domain error:

```
 $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: 'your url',
            headers: {
                'api-key':'CSDP-001',
                'accept':'application/json'
            },
            data: form_data, 

            success:function(data){  
            }
       });
```

Answer (score -4):

We can fix the problem by placing base tag on our html.

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.otherdomain.com/xyz/">
</head>
```