# Making AJAX() call result into Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, proxy-server

I was trying to send a form details to a folder containing the php script to process and validated it using AJAX() method ,

But I am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error . I know this is cross browser problem but I am not able to find out a solution for this .

1. Writing a Proxy server is one option . Can someone help me out with this I am very new to all this .

here is my code

```
<script>
    *<![CDATA[*/
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#abusoForm #enviar").livequery("click", function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Click is working");
            var hidden = $('#mensaje').val();
            var category = $('#opcmarcar').val();
            var name = $('#nombre').val();
            var phone = $('#telefono').val();
            var mail = $('#email').val();
            var cf_mail = $('#confirma_email').val();
            var k = ""
            var z = "anotherdomain.com";
            var otro = $('#otro_email').val();
            var E = $("#abusoForm #enviar").val();

            //Ajax call happening here 
            var vajx = $.ajax({
                url: z,
                type: "POST",
                data: { 
                    'h': hidden, 
                    'c': category,
                    'n': name,
                    'p': phone ,
                    'm': mail,
                    'cm': cf_mail,
                    'otro1': otro,
                    "enviar": E,
                    async: false
                }
            }).responseText;

            //Now I have to use the variable vajx to post a message about the submition of the form ;
            $('#resultip').html(vajx);
        })
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I read this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/  but cant understand much

. Another possiblity would be to use CORS but I am not getting it how to use the script to use with JQUERY function AJAX().

Comment: Assuming that the url contained in `z` is outside of your control, writing a server-side proxy is your only option.

Comment: In short: you can't fetch content from an external URL using AJAX alone. Use a PHP script that resides on your server to do the fetching and then send the requests to this PHP script to have the data transferred to your client-side code.

Comment: Yes, you can make a call to PHP script on your server and have that php script call the remote url through CURL.

Comment: Its possible if server side code support jsonp

Comment: Do you have control of the server? If so you can set its CORS headers, its simple!

Comment: @NickM How to see the CORS?

Comment: Sorry I meant "set", not "see". Do you control the server where you PHP script lies?

Comment: @NickM yes I know the file where its located I can modify it .

Comment: But can you modify the server's apache config files?

Comment: @NickM no bro I donot have any access to it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give me some example how to write a proxy in php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54508/discussion-between-vikram-anand-bhushan-and-nick-m).

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan unfortunately you cannot use my solution as setting up CORS headers on a server requires access to the apache configs.