# Google's new reCaptcha site verification returns no responce

Tags: javascript, cors, recaptcha, verification

I do [site verification](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) after getting `g-recaptcha-response` thru user verification.

I send xhr POST with parameters and get 200 OK, yet NO response as it should be:

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "error-codes": [...]   // optional
}
```

### Code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
var onReturnCallback = function(response) { 
document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = response; // works well
//alert('grecaptcha.getResponse() = ' + grecaptcha.getResponse()); // works well too
$.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", 
          { secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            response: response,
            remoteip :  "<?php echo $ip;?>" // optional, does not influence an empty result           
           }).complete(function( data ) {
                alert( "Data returned from POST: " + data.toString() );
                console.dir(data);
              });  

};
</script>
Form.  
<form method="post"> 
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdYKQkTAAAAAD9K6-kHspFUPUnftw1RxP5_awi0" data-callback="onReturnCallback" data-theme="light">       </div>
<input name="send" type="submit" />
</form>
```

The object that I print in console is totally empty (except for `statusText='error'`), see the [shot](http://joxi.ru/MAjRad1hJpY8Ae).

There is other error in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://tarex.ru' is therefore not allowed access.

How to deal with it? Can i change the origin header? How to verify?

The [link](http://tarex.ru/testdir/recaptcha/form.php) to the demo.

Comment: You can not do XHR requests to hosts, that are not explicitly whitelisted by the http response sent by your server. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607901/cross-origin-request-blocked-on

Comment: @SebastianS, thank you. It has helped me. You might form an answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to make XHRs ("AJAX requests") to hosts other than the one serving a website due to the so-called "same origin policy" (SOP) to prevent XSS attacks.

However you can post to the reCaptcha site from a php proxy, that you run on your own host. An example for this is given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608173/4014509). This also prevents your secret from being public to people looking at your client-side source code.

Another possibility (depending on the service you want to use) is [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). As XHRs are prohibited, but loading scripts from foreign hosts is not, it is possible to add the name of a callback function via query parameters to the script URL. This function is then invoked as soon as the foreign resource is loaded. But as far as I know reCaptcha does not support JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

reCaptcha purportedly supports jsonp as a legal value of the dataType parameter.