# jQuery ajax error - No transport, Cross-origin request blocked

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am making an jquery ajax call as shown in below code snippet. Getting "No transport error" on IE8 and "Cross-origin request blocked" o Firefox browsers.

However it works fine on external REST clients, when I call the service. Such as chrome advance rest client, postman etc.

Please let me know if anything wrong in the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        var url = 'https://testserver/accounts/123456/accountdetails/loaninfo';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                'Api-Key': 'MyAppKey',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(status);
            },
            error: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(status);
              }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: it's a CORS issue and postman is not restricted by CORS. Not hard to research that error

Comment: any idea ..how can i solve it?

Comment: yes...there are tons of posts here...and all over the web. This gets asked numerous times a day. If you control that server you need to implement CORS on your api ... otherwise since you need auth headers will need to use a proxy

Comment: in the above url i am passing account no. 123456 as input in the url itself. does it look right?

Comment: that has nothing to do with the error which is a security restriction issue

Comment: can you elaborate little bit on "you need auth headers will need to use a proxy"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607901/cross-origin-request-blocked-on

Comment: Duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error