# GET requests cross sites

Tags: javascript, https, get

So I noticed you can GET request (curl/wget) youtube.com and it's paths from the command line, but not from any website (except youtube obviously) using XMLHttpRequest due to YT not allowing cross-origin etc. My question is, is there ANY way around this?

Comment: see [**Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15005500/1407478) for multiple online solutions, you can also [create a proxy by yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23607901/1407478) (PHP example).

Comment: _..due to YT not allowing cross-origin._ This is wrong. That's due to [the same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) which is implemented by client (browser), not youtube.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to access youtube data then you can use their API's. https://developers.google.com/youtube/.

If you want to access any other site through XMLHttpRequest, then it is not possible, without the permission of the other sites.

Answer (score 0):

By default it's restricted to make such cross-origin requests.
There is exception, you can use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) technique, which is allowing doing that. Howewer, service which you're asking for a data should implement possibility to answer with JSONP.