# Providing this error 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in firefox' in website

Tags: wordpress, mozilla

In my wordpress website there have a issue:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Request Blocked on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607901/cross-origin-request-blocked-on)

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing this is the actual error